# Update multiples row. Password plain text to password hash in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I have a table with multiple users. Today users are in plane text password.

Now I created a new column with `VARCHAR (256)` to put the password hash of each user in a column called `password`.

I made a PHP that obtains every user and make an update corresponding with the password hash:

```
<?php
require("Db.class.php");
require("password.php");
$db = new Db();
$result = $db->query("SELECT idUser, pass FROM user");

if(count($result) == 0){
    echo "Error!";
    $db->CloseConnection();
}

else if(count($result) > 0){
    foreach($result as $user){
        $passDB = $user["pass"];
        $idUser = $user["idUser"];
        $hash = password_hash($passDB, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $resultUser = $db->query("UPDATE user SET password = :hash WHERE idUser = :idUser",
        array("hash" => $hash, "idUser" => $idUser)); 
    }
    $db->CloseConnection();
}
?>
```

The php works for a few rows. Then, the SQL not update following rows because is too inefficient.

Is there a better way to do what I want? I have to mix php with mysql because I have to convert plain text password with password_hash function from the library: [password compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to do this in a single query.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

The code below assumes isUser is a PRIMARY KEY or is UNIQUE column in the table.

```
<?php
require("Db.class.php");
require("password.php");
$db = new Db();
$result = $db->query("SELECT idUser, pass FROM user");
if(count($result) == 0){
    echo "Error!";
    $db->CloseConnection();
}
else if(count($result) > 0){
$str="INSERT INTO user (idUser,pass,password) VALUES ";
    foreach($result as $user){
        $passDB = $user["pass"];
        $idUser = $user["idUser"];
        $hash = password_hash($passDB, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $str.="('".$idUser."','".$passDB."','".$hash."'),";
    }
    $str=rtrim($str,",");
    $str.="ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password=VALUES(password);";
    $resultUser = $db->query($str); 
    $db->CloseConnection();
}
?>
```

Comment: What problems are you still facing? If you can tell in detail,  may be I can help.

Comment: Tomorrow I'm gonna try it with another way with your help. So after that I'm gonna answer you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On your query

```
$resultUser = $db->query("UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD(:hash)
 WHERE idUser = :idUser",
```

Refer here [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html](http://mySQL%20Reference%20HASH%20password)
 then you don't need to convert at php and pass again

or if you don't want to re do array.

```
$resultUser = $db->query("UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD('".$hash."') 
WHERE idUser = '".$idUser."'",
```